# VESC and wireless receiver setup

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit

Trying a DIY VESC project, but very limited knowledge of circuit boards and connections.  I have dual Maytech 100a V6 VESC and wireless receiver, but I don't know how to connect them.  The remote is supposed to drive both VESC and motors.  I don't have any Hall sensors.  Too many extra pins and potential combinations.
[image]

[image]

I am supposed to connect the two VESC via the CANbus port 5.  But I can't figure out how to connect the receiver to the VESC.  I have supposedly have UART or PWM potential.  The pins don't seem to line up right with the included connectors (7 pin, split 6 pin, or 3 pin).  Is it just one connection or do I have to connect in multiple places?  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

connect rc controllers to the ppm port
Rx throttle to ppm port
then follow the vesctool wizard to map it

Comment: Can you expand this answer?

Comment: the reciever for your controller will have a throttle output....+ve..-ve...signal.  Connect them to the ppm of the vesc accordingly

Comment: Awesome, please edit the answer, please use proper grammer and caps